# How can we lookup column names of one table with data in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

If any one can help me

I have scenario were I need to take the col name of one table (there is no data only the col name) and then search those col name in the data available in another table .

I can manually do it like take a col name and then search in another table using like and I see it exist.
But can some help me know how we can write a SQL script for this.

Answer (score 0):

SQL :

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName'
```

MYSQL

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to compare the entire database it could work like this, you can restrict it to single table as well

```
        SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT 
                    c.TABLE_SCHEMA_S,
                    c.TABLE_SCHEMA_D,
                    c.TABLE_NAME_S,
                    c.TABLE_NAME_D,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(c.COLUMN_NAME)  COLUMN_NAMES
            FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT
                    a.TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_SCHEMA_S,
                    b.TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_SCHEMA_D,
                    a.TABLE_NAME TABLE_NAME_S,
                    b.TABLE_NAME TABLE_NAME_D,
                    b.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                information_schema.COLUMNS a
            INNER JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS b ON a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
                AND a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME
            WHERE
                a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'first-db-name'
                    AND b.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'second-db-name') c
            GROUP BY c.TABLE_NAME_S) d;
```

Comment: Thanks Ejaz,
I think using the given query we can compare the column of one table with another table,  but in my case i want to compare column of one table with the data in another table. like in other table I have data store as text under one column and I should be able to lookup all the col from table a in the column of table b.  table b have col with hundereds of rows and I need to search in one col across all the row. the data is in text form so have to use like %%

Comment: you can generate queries from these results.  With single group by and group concatenate this can yield a query for comparing the results with union by placing the rows from one table next to the other for visual inspection.   The other you can generate queries producing left and right joins field by field and display the unmatching results only.  you can also try some db. compare tool and there are many out there.